# Handling Facebook as alternative login

Tags: ios, node.js, facebook

I'm developing an iOS app with a server-side component. Users can create and login to accounts with an email/password combination. I'm also building in an option to alternatively login via Facebook. If the user logs in via Facebook I will need to create an account for them using the email we get from Facebook - but what do I do about the password? The server obviously requires a password to create an account. Should I use something like their Facebook user ID as a password (doesn't seem secure), do I force them to create a password? What's the standard practice here?

Comment: force user to set password ,then only if user like to change password then he want to know old password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can set a button text or alert saying "Use Facebook data for Registration".
2. After clicking on the button, you can redirect the user to the registration screen.
3. Fill up all the data with his facebook data then leave the password and confirm passwords blank to let him choose his password.

Trying to use his personal Facebook data as password may be the cause for rejection of your app on Appstore.